# MNIST data classification not working on Google Colab

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, google-colaboratory

I am trying to train the MNIST digit dataset using deep MLP on Google colab. I have reshaped the input and performed data preprocessing.The model code is as below:

```
    #define the model layers
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, input_shape = input_shape, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Dense(128,activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dense(64,activation = "relu"))
    model.add(Dropout(0.1))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(tar_class,activation = "sigmoid"))

    model.compile(optimizer = "adam",
          loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
          metrics = ["accuracy"])

    model.summary()

    history = model.fit(X_train,y_train,
                epochs = 10,
                validation_split = 0.1,
                batch_size = 64,
                verbose = True)
```

When I run the model.fit code, the training happens only for 844 samples in the dataset and not for 60000 samples. However, this code works well in my local jupyter notebook. I want to work on Colab so that I can use GPU to train the model, which is quick compared to my local machine.

Can anyone please help me out here?

Comment: how do you know it only trains for 844 samples?

Comment: Can you print `X_train.shape` and `y_train.shape` and share the result?

Comment: @Reza when I train the model, each epoch shows 1/844....sometimes it changes to random numbers like 938, 1644 etc.

Comment: @Grayrigel Shape of X_train: (60000, 28, 28, 1)
Shape of y_train: (60000, 10)
Shape of X_test: (10000, 28, 28, 1)
Shape of y_test: (10000, 10)

i can share the GitHub link for the code if you want to take a look at the whole code

Comment: @Reza i can share the GitHub link for the code if you want to take a look at the whole code

Comment: @user11619814 That looks okay. It would be nice to see your code.

Comment: @Grayrigel here is the link https://github.com/gprashmi/MNIST_digit_classification/blob/master/MNIST_classification.ipynb

Comment: @Grayrigel I am facing this problem when I run the code in Kaggle notebook as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 844 does not represent the number of samples it is getting trained on, but it represents number of steps per epoch.

**What is the number of steps?**
The number of steps is equivalent no of passes ie`(1 pass = 1 Forward Pass + 1 Backward pass)` that occurs in an epoch.
The number of steps is calculated as:

```
no_of_steps_per_epoch = ceil(Total_no_of_samples / batch_size)
```

For completion of one epoch, you have to iterate over the entire dataset. ie. iterate over all the batches.

For eg:
X_train has 60000 samples.
You have specified validation_split as 0.1. Therefore, 0.1 % of this X_train will be used as validation data. ie. It will not be used for training.

Therefore, the number of samples for training will be (60000 - 6000) = 54000.

Now you have specified batch_size as 64.
Therefore,

```
no_of_steps_per_epoch = ceil(54000/64) = ceil(843.74) = 844
```

This is how you get 844.

It does not mean you are training on 844 samples.

Comment: oh okay....so that means the 54000 is getting trained in 844 steps right?

Comment: Also,  if I do not specify the batch size, then the no_of_steps_pre_epoch will be equal to the training samples (54000) right?

Comment: By default, the batch_size would be 32. See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit). If you want to have steps_per_epoch equal to the number of samples set `batch_size = 1`.

Comment: oh okay...got it... thank you...but when I run the same code in jupyter notebook in my local, the training shows 1/540000(samples) for each epoch rather than 1/steps_per_epoch...is there  a reason for this?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: When I run this code in my local machine and not on google colab , each epoch run as follows: Epoch 1/10
54000/54000 [==============================] - 904s 17ms/step - loss: 0.3527 - accuracy: 0.9000 - val_loss: 0.2674 - val_accuracy: 0.9262

Comment: Here the steps_per_epoch is not considered?

Comment: 54000 you see on the logs are the steps per epoch. As i said in the ans they do not represent the number of samples. If you set your batch_size as 1, you can interpret them as number of samples. However, in essence they are steps per epoch.