# Tensorflow input generator ran out of data

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter, tensorflow2.0, kaggle

So I was trying to implement this [kaggle code](https://www.kaggle.com/twhitehurst3/stanford-dogs-keras-vgg16) into my Jupyter to test the performance of my laptop.
There were some modifications of the code to fit the my version of environments:

```
#from scipy.ndimage import imread 
from imageio import imread
```

Upon block[11], i received the error as below
[image: error message]

Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What is the shape of x_train and y_train?

Comment: (1161, 150, 150, 3) and (1161, 10) respectively @AniketBote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified `step_per_epoch` incorrectly.

The steps_per_epoch should be equal to

```
steps_per_epoch = ceil(number_of_samples / batch_size)
```

For your case

```
steps_per_epoch = ceil(1161 / 16) = ceil(72.56) = 73
```

Try specifying `steps_per_epoch = 73`

As you can your entire data is exhausted in 73 steps. Now, if you specify `steps_per_epoch` any higher than 73 ie 74

There is no data available. Therefore you get `input generator ran out of data`

More Information:
Model training comprises of two parts forward pass and backward pass.

```
1 train step = 1 forward pass + 1 backward pass
```

A single train step(1 forward pass + 1 backward pass) is calculated on a single batch.

So if you have `100` samples and your batch size is `10`.
Your model will have 10 train steps.

Epoch: Epoch is defined as complete iteration over the dataset.
Therefore, for your model to completely iterate over the dataset of 100 samples, it should undergo 10 train steps.

This train step is nothing but `steps_per_epoch`.

The `steps_per_epoch` argument is usually specified when you give infinite data generator to your `fit()` command and does not need to be specified if you have finite data.

Comment: yeah it works but 2 questions.
Why `steps_per_epoch = ceil(number_of_samples / batch_size)` ? Is there something to reference from?
It raised another issue `PermissionDeniedError: Failed to create a directory: .; Permission denied [Op:MergeV2Checkpoints]` ?   @Aniket Bote

Comment: What is the issue? I'll update the answer accordingly along with information on `steps_per_epoch`.

Comment: I have updated the answer with more information on `steps_per_epoch`. You can also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63713842/mnist-data-classification-not-working-on-google-colab/63716643#63716643). The issue is most probably due to error in your specified callbacks. Try removing the callbacks and see if it works.